# Artifacts not building in a Tomcat based Java Server Pages web app in IntelliJ

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, artifact, intellij-15

I've been fighting with a strange issue for a few hours now. This is the second Java Server Pages project I have created, and the other one is working fine. The difference with the new one is that it is an imported project with examples for my university course.

The issue is that the Tomcat artifacts are not being created when the project is built, so the build generates the following errors:

```
[2019-04-12 04:01:02,433] Artifact examples: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2019-04-12 04:01:02,436] Artifact examples: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/home/IdeaProjects/oop-examples/j2ee-web/out/artifacts/examples not found for the web module.
```

This appears to be because the folder out/artifacts/examples and its contents are never created in the project.

In the log it says the following:

```
019-04-12 16:01:02,435 [ 163467]   INFO - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/home/IdeaProjects/oop-examples/j2ee-web/out/artifacts/examples not found for the web module. 
com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/home/IdeaProjects/oop-examples/j2ee-web/out/artifacts/examples not found for the web module.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.doDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:132)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$4.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:120)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:245)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:135)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$2.setDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:90)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$DeploymentModelOperation.doSetDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:272)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$3.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:100)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:245)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeployWithUndeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:107)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.startDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminServerBase.startDeploy(TomcatAdminServerBase.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.startDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$0(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:53)
    at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$1(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.lambda$run$0(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:198)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:224)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/home/IdeaProjects/oop-examples/j2ee-web/out/artifacts/examples not found for the web module.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.addApplicationContext(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$4.doPerform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:283)
    ... 28 more
```

I have tried invalidating caches and restarting. I also have tried emptying out the 'out' folder and rebuilding the project.

Likewise I have gone to 'Run>Edit Configurations>Tomcat 9.0.17>Deployment>Edit Artifact' and tried changing the settings, including the most obvious one, which was a checkbox saying, 'include in project build'.

Nothing seems to work to get the out/artifacts folder and its content to build as part of the project, so I hope someone knows what may be going on.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you have Build artifact step in Before launch in Tomcat Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: It is there, but for some reason the artifact is not building.